# Need help with perl error in using DBD::mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, perl, environment-variables

When I run a perl script which uses DBD::mysql , I get the error message:

```
install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load '/home/y/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/i686-linux-64int/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so'
for module DBD::mysql: libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at /home/y/lib/perl5/5.8/i686-linux-64int/DynaLoader.pm line 230. at (eval 30) line 3
```

I am new to perl, but from what I understand it needs mysql.so and it knows the path.

`/home/y/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/i686-linux-64int/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so` is present.

Then why the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file that is missing is `libmysqlclient.so.16`, not `mysql.so`. It comes with the `mysqlclient` package on some distributions.

Comment: ok, I can see libmysqlclient.so is present. Let me check if it is on path. What is the difference between libmysqlclient.so.16 and libmysqlclient.so ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure /etc/ld.so.conf contains /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql and /usr/local/mysql/ . If not, add them and run ldconfig.