# Need help with perl error in using DBD::mysql

Tags: mysql, perl, development-environment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need help with perl error in using DBD::mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456215/need-help-with-perl-error-in-using-dbdmysql)

When I run a perl script which uses DBD::mysql , I get the error message:

> install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load '/home/y/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/i686-linux-64int/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so' for module DBD::mysql: libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /home/y/lib/perl5/5.8/i686-linux-64int/DynaLoader.pm line 230.
>    at (eval 30) line 3

I am new to perl, but from what I understand it needs mysql.so and it knows the path.

/home/y/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/i686-linux-64int/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so is present.

Then why the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The file that is missing is libmysqlclient.so.16. It comes with the mysqlclient package on some distributions.

Also, Make sure /etc/ld.so.conf contains /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql and /usr/local/mysql/ . If not, add them and run ldconfig.